# padrino 0.11.4 and mongoid 3.0.23 blog - posts not showing in front-end

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, haml, padrino

After successfully following [this tutorial](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/blog-tutorial), I tried creating a similar blog using mongoid as a stepping stone for a later project. Admin setup and model+controller creation went well, but posts don't show up in the front-end.

The admin is creating both users and posts and posts are being created with an associated user:

[image: mongo shell]

No error is thrown, nothing in browser console, the "posts" div is created, but it comes out empty.

Thanks for reading.

(edited)

UPDATE:

issue was in the ActiveRecord syntax used in [posts controller](https://github.com/padrino/sample_blog/blob/master/app/controllers/posts.rb). the following works with Mongoid:

```
PadrinoMongoid::App.controllers :posts do

  get :index do
    @posts = Post.order_by(:created_at.desc)
    render 'posts/index'
  end

  get :show, :with => :id do
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    render 'posts/show'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.all(:order => 'created_at desc')` is not a valid syntax to sort objects in Mongoid. Correct one would be `Post.order_by(:created_at.asc)`.

Comment: thanks. "find_by_id()" is also not a method in mongoid, "find()" is. headslap.